# How to disable to run an .exe written via Python at a specific time

Tags: python, windows, exe, python-3.4

I have a script and I'll convert it to exe. I'll use `datetime` module, if 2 days passed after the program ran first, I want to disable the user to use the program again.

I'm checking the date with this

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime.today() #when the user run the program first time
                     #I'll save this variable into somewhere encrypted
                     #everytime program will take this variable from there when it's running

y = datetime.now()   #whenever program is running checking the current time

if y.day == x.day+2: #after 2 days
    #here is the problem
    #user must not will be able to use the program again
```

How to make the program not available after 2 days? I want the program run like a trial version.

Comment: Reason for down-vote?

Comment: Maybe because you are asking for code without demonstrating what you've tried, other than finding out today's date.

Comment: @SiHa I can't try anything since I don't know what to do about this. It's not a homework and I'm not new here.

Comment: `if y.day == x.day+2: sys.exit()`? Note that you probably want `>=`

Comment: @SiHa  thought that but if the user delete the program and download again, `x` will be a new `datetime.today()`. So that will not work. If the user delete encrypted file which is holding `x`, that's it.

Comment: Whatever. Your question, I would suggest, is not a good fit for SO. "How do I do  <vague requirement>" is either off-topic or too-broad IMHO

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to permanently block that computer from running the same program - the user could always delete any files that the program touched, to make it seem like she never used it to begin with.

(Technically you can get close by making the program ask your computer (over the internet or something) for permission to run, but that seems way over the top for anything reasonable.)

Comment: Some programs have trial versions, do you know how it works? Are they using a special program/script for that?

Comment: They either put some value into your Windows registry, just like how you put `x` into "somewhere encrypted", or they do the online thing I described.

Comment: Well I need to put a value to Windows registry as you said. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the file your code is running:

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime.today() #when the user run the program first time
                 #I'll save this variable into somewhere encrypted
                 #everytime program will take this variable from there when it's running

y = datetime.now()   #whenever program is running checking the current time

if y.day == x.day+2: #after 2 days
    with open(__file__,"w") as file:
         file.write("print 'Your two day trial has expired!'")
         exit()
```

Comment: if the user delete that file, that'll not work. That's the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? This code overwrites to contents of its file. There is nothing to get back by deleting

Comment: Well if the user delete the program and download again, x will be a new datetime.today(). So that will not work. If the user delete encrypted file which is holding x, that'll blow up on my face.